# Windows server 2016 will no longer connect to internet after a reboot

Tags: networking, internet-connection, windows-server-2016

So i was in the process of simply renewing my certificates for this server and during the process i decided to reboot it.

Right after that happened, when going back into the server i was no longer able to connect to the Internet from that server.

1. Cant ping gateway or GoogleDNS.
2. Reset TCP Stack.
3. Tried adding a PCI Ethernet Adapter including USB.
4. Ran some Windows Repair tool from Tweaking.com.
5. Checked for services that may have not started properly.
6. Toggled IPv6 on and off to see if it would work.
7. Tried setting DHCP elsewhere (my ASA) so it pulls DHCP and see if it works then.
8. Tried using different IP Address.
9. Removed controller from Device Manager and rescanned.
10. Checked routing tables.
11. Reboot my ASA. This DID somewhat work, i could ping 8.8.8.8 but could not browse the Internet. But after rebooting the server again, it went back to not working at all.

I think the only thing i have not tried is to completely remove the drivers of the NIC but then again it did the same thing with other NICs.

What is odd is that i CAN ping other devices on the network just not the Gateway for some odd reason.

At this point im just completely out of ideas other than download some updates as for some reason it has not updated in months and hopefully an update can fix this issue?

I would really hate to start from scratch as this server is hosting my Exchange email and other services that are a pain to migrate to a temp VM while i would reinstall. I do have backups however but a but unsure if i should do that, could break AD sync with my secondary DC.

Any tips? or have i missed something? I think this is everything i have tried...

Comment: I see that you mentioned Windows Server 2016. This version of Windows has a mode in which alien network traffic (i.e. to untrusted networks) is blocked while you are maintaining it. This mode could very easily be disabled in Server Manager. Only, I've forgotten how. The problem is, it was very simple and convenient to disable it; hence, I don't remember.

Comment: Also, please be sure to inspect Windows Firewall status. (Not just its rules, but also simple things like whether it is on or in strict mode.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Had no idea there was such mode but I'll see if I can find it